# I can't call Widget for a new Admin Plugin in NopCommerce

Tags: c#, .net, html-helper, nopcommerce

I Create a New plugin to manage back Office menus,

I implement the interface IWidgetPlugin to create a new widget zone :

```
public IList<string> GetWidgetZones()
{
     return new List<string>(){ 
         "ebm_MenuManager_BackOffice"
     };
}
```

And I had called this widget zone from one view "_AdminLayout.csHtml" under Nop.Admin project with the extended helper @Html.Widget

`@Html.Widget("ebm_MenuManager_BackOffice")`

how can i display my widget zone in this back office view with the widget call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, for those who are interested please check this link from nopcommerce community wher i asked the same question :

http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/35927/i-cant-call-widget-for-a-new-admin-plugin.aspx

Best Regards.